# Anyway to assign custom post types to a specific category?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

Is there anyway to assign all new posts that have a custom post_type to a specific category? For example, say I have a post_type that is for Actors. Is there anyway to assign any post that is under Actors to a "People" category? (but without displaying the Category box in the WordPress Admin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can first remove the category meta box from Actors post type edit screen like this

```
 function remove_custom_taxonomy()
 {
    remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv', 'custom_post_slug', 'side' );
 }

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_custom_taxonomy' );
```

then create a function that will add the category on save_post

```
function default_category($post_id){
     // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

     // check for post type
    if ('Actors' == $_POST['post_type']) {
            $Default_category_id = '23';
        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id,$Default_category_id , 'category', ture );
     }

}
```

hope this helps

Comment: It appears to be adding the custom post types to the correct category, but when I look on the Categories page in the WordPress admin it says 0. Any ideas why the correct number isn't showing up?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think it has to do code, if you paste it here i could get a better idea. by code i mean the register_post_type function and any other custom code in relevance

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to add "capability_type=>'post'" to the register_post_type arguments in order to get it to appear.

Comment: glad i could help :)