# Assign category a default post type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, categories, functions, autosave

This one has been bothering me for a few days now, so I'd really appreciate any help you can give me.

**Problem overview:**

I have a plugin which automatically creates a post and assigns the category "YouTube" whenever a new video is uploaded to a YouTube channel. This part works fine.
However - I'm also wanting the post to be assigned the post type "Video". The plugin doesn't allow for this type of customisation, so this will have to be done in php.

**Where I've looked:** (included for those who like to say "Have you read the forums?")

[WordPress Codex Set Post Format](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_format)

[WordPress Codex In Category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/in_category)

[WordPress Stack Exchange 1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26416/add-category-to-custom-post-type-automatically-using-category-slug)

[WordPress Stack Exchange 2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8217/anyway-to-assign-custom-post-types-to-a-specific-category)

**What I've tried:**

A few different attempts aren't getting me any results (not white screen of deathing me either so that's a bonus?)

1: (not sure where I'd need to tell that function to run)

```
//* If post has category YouTube - set post type to video
function default_post_type($post_id) {
  // check autosave
  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return $post_id;

    if (in_category('YouTube')) {
        set_post_format($post_id, 'video');
    }
  }
}
```

2: (mixing it up a little bit, because ... reasons?)

```
//* If post has category YouTube - set post type to video
// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
  return $post_id;

  function default_post_type($post_id) {
    if (in_category('YouTube')) {
        set_post_format($post_id, 'video');
    }
  }
}
```

3: (so then I thought "Why even use a function at all?")

```
//* If post has category YouTube - set post type to video
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
  return $post_id;

  if (in_category('YouTube', $post_id)) {
    set_post_format($post_id, 'video');
  }
}
```

Appreciate any help - even if you can tell me why what I've done is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm also wanting the post to be assigned the post type "Video".

You can't just change a post to a different Post Type. There is a difference between "Post Type" and "Post Format".

From your examples I assume you would like to change the "Post Format", as per the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_format, you would need to paste that code in functions.php.
Then call that function in your template. eg:

```
<!-- Loop Start here -->

    //* If post has category YouTube - set post type to video
    default_post_type($post_id) {

<!-- Loop End -->
```

Comment: Thanks Nath. You're right, I want to change the post format - so I'll look into that solution.

Before I accept your answer, one thing to clarify:
You say to call the function in the template - but this isn't actually meant to be run on any page. It's more a backend thing so that every time a new post is automatically created by the YouTube plugin with the Category "YouTube" - that particular post is also given the correct post format.

So really I need to run the function independantly - that's what the "if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {}" is for I guess.

Comment: I see. I was just basing my answer off of what I read in the codex. I've never actually had to change a post format before haha!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this issue - the working code looks like this (placed in the functions.php file):

```
function default_post_type($post_id) {
  if (in_category('YouTube')) {
    set_post_format($post_id, 'video');
  }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'default_post_type' );
```

Happy WordPressing